# Why is login process's command line partially wiped off when queried via /proc/PID/cmdline?

Tags: login

I'm facing a strange situation on Ubuntu 20.04 .

Starting with a root shell, I run `login -h selflinux -f chj` to log user `chj` into a new Bash shell. Then I try to query the login process's command line, via `cat /proc/7809/cmdline`, but I cannot see the complete original command line. The content after `-f` seems to be wiped off.

I'd like to know, why do this happen?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't keep the user name on purpose, and because that file is readable by anybody? Other longer commands without the user name work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The user name is not logged in the information for security reasons (I assume, but do not know for certain). If you change the order of the command line options, observe that the user name is still the only thing not shown:

Command:

```
# login -f doug -h s19
```

Result:

```
$ ps aux | grep login
root        1602  0.0  0.0  11832  4864 pts/0    S    11:45   0:00 login -f      -h s19
$ cat /proc/1602/cmdline
login-f-hs19
```

You can try to make changes in `/etc/login.defs` to override the default behaviour. I tried but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Yeah it looks like [login.c](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/login.c) overwrites the username during argument processing (`strzero (argv[optind]);`, where `strzero` eventually resolves to a call to [memset](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man3/memset.3.html))

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you very much for pointing out the source code. I think you presented the exact answer. The login's code deliberately hides the login user name from being seen by /proc/PID virtual file system.